# Python client socket not receiving data from TCP server

Tags: python, sockets, data-transfer

I'm trying to build a fake money transfer program with sockets in python. Everything is working perfectly except the "name" and "amount" transfer from the server to the client. When someone clicks receive on the client interface, the server is supposed to send the client the name of the person who sent the money and the amount. The problem is that the client is not receiving the data sent from the server. When you click the "receive" button, the interface just freezes then crashes. From the debugging I've done, I'm pretty sure the server is sending the name and amount, but the client is not receiving it. I honestly have no idea why it's not working. Everything I did should work like it has numerous other times throughout the program. This one has got me stumped.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

[CODE]

Server.py:

```
import socket
import threading

HOST = '192.168.1.6'
PORT = 9090


def client_fun(client, addr):
    global transfers
    print(f"{addr} just connected!")
    connected = True
    while connected:


    msg = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

    if msg == "RECEIVE_CHECK":
        usrn = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        transfers_ = open("transfers.txt", "r")
        transfers = str(transfers_.readlines())
        transfers = transfers.split("+")
        transfers[0] = transfers[0].replace("[", "")
        transfers[0] = transfers[0].replace("'", "")
        transfers.pop()

        names = []
        for tran in transfers:
            tran_ = tran.split("-")
            i = 0
            while i <= len(tran):
                names.append(tran_[2])
                i += 1
        if usrn in names:
            client.send("OK".encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            client.send("NO".encode('utf-8'))

        if usrn in names:
            for tran in transfers:
                tran_ = tran.split("-")
                if usrn == tran_[2]:
                    name = str(tran_[0])
                    amount = str(tran_[1])
                    client.send(name.encode('utf-8'))
                    client.send(amount.encode('utf-8'))
                    account_file = usrn + "_" + "account.txt"
                    account_r = open(account_file, "r")
                    account_r = str(account_r.readlines())
                    account_r = account_r.replace(']', '')
                    account_r = account_r.replace('[', '')
                    account_r = account_r.replace("'", "")
                    try:
                        account_r = int(account_r)
                    except:
                        print("Can't Convert Str to Int!")
                        break
                    new_amount = int(tran_[1]) + account_r
                    account_w = open(account_file, "w")
                    account_w.write(str(new_amount))
                    account_w.close()
                    tran = tran + "+"
                    transFers_ = open("transfers.txt", "r")
                    transFers = str(transFers_.readlines())
                    transFers_.close()
                    transFers = transFers.replace(']', '')
                    transFers = transFers.replace('[', '')
                    transFers = transFers.replace("'", "")
                    transFers = transFers.replace(tran, '')
                    transFers_ = open("transfers.txt", 'w+')
                    transFers_.write(transFers)
                    transFers_.close()
                    print("Excepted!")
        else:
            print("Nothing Here!")


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()
print("Server is listening!")

while True:
    c_socket, address = server.accept()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=client_fun, args=(c_socket, address))
    thread.start()
```

Client.py:

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.1.6'
PORT = 9090
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def receive(usrn):
    socket.send("RECEIVE_CHECK".encode('utf-8'))
    socket.send(usrn.encode('utf-8'))

    c = socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    if c == "OK":
        try:
            print("Trying to except....")
            name = socket.recv(2000).decode('utf-8')
            amount = socket.recv(2000).decode('utf-8')
            print("Excepted!")
            messagebox.showwarning("Continue?", f"{name} has sent you ${amount}", icon="question")
            messagebox.showwarning("Info", f"${amount} has just been transferred to your account!", icon="info")
            menu(usrn)
        except:
            print("Error!")
    else:
        print("Nothing Today!")
```

Comment: One send doesn't equal one receive. There's a good chance the server sends "Bob Smith" and "2000" and the client receives "Bob Smith2000" and then just waits for more data

Comment: @user253751 Ohhhh. That would make sense. So if I just sent one message and then split it into a tuple, that would work?

Comment: possible. There's no such thing as messages in TCP. Only bytes.

Comment: You normally send 4 bytes of message length as a network order integer first as a message then read and accumulate that many bytes on the client side to be sure your *"message"* is complete. Send the initial size in network byte order (see documentation for `struct pack`) to ensure client and server agree even if of differing endianness.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys! @user253751 I figured it out. I sent the name and amount as one string, then split it on the client side which worked great!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the info. I'll change the code right away!

Comment: @IsaacJohnson Yeah, that is one way to make this demonstration work for the time being. It's not reliable, but you'll learn better ways as you get more experienced, so I won't preach to you now.

Comment: @user253751 